# NAND Simplified with xy + !x z

Tags: circuit-analysis, logic-gates, nand

I've been trying to work on a few problems, though I'm not sure how to rewrite this a few circuits using only NAND/NOR -->

an example is shown below;

[image]

How am I able to rewrite only using NAND + NOR gates if anyone is able to help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: if you put bubbles on both ends of a wire, it doesn't change the circuit function.

Comment: @The Photon I'm sorry, I posted the wrong problem. I had already done that one earlier by reduction

I will update the picture now

Comment: OK, you should still be able to solve this using the rules in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Three hints that can solve this:

1. You can implement an inverter by either a NAND or a NOR gate with both inputs connected to the same signal.
2. You can put bubbles on both ends of a wire without changing the circuit function.
3. An AND gate with both inputs inverted is equivalent to a NOR gate, and an OR gate with both inputs inverted is equivalent to a NAND gate. Graphically, this can be thought of as "pushing the bubbles through" the gate, leaving one bubble on the output and changing the type of gate. Or, in symbols \$\bar{A}\bar{B} =\overline{A+B}\$.

Comment: @user209499 ThePhoton's point 3 is commonly called DeMorgan's Theorem. You should get to know it well.